# Best way to create JSONP web service in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

what is the best way to create a JSONP web service so I can call JSON with a normal xhrGet? I am using ASP.NET 4.0. I have searched online but it only shows ASP.NET 3.5 and under.

Comment: Also this is in C# if that matters.

Comment: You should use WCF for all new web service development, and not the legacy ASMX services. Alternatively, use ASP.NET MVC to create the service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On .net 4.0 you can set crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled on a webHttpBinding and have WCF handle the rest for you.

I can't post my own code, but [this article](http://bendewey.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery/) was extremely helpful in figuring that stuff out for me.

Note though that in JSONP, unhandled exceptions cannot be caught properly.

Comment: This was a perfect link. I've been lamenting for ages not being able to get it to work (ages in Konrad-time, that is - it's about a day or two in human time). Less than 15 minutes after the article I got me a working example. Huge thanks!